# data-rel="back" not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am building an app using `jQuery mobile` and `phonegap`

The app is ready, and works absolutely fine on `Android, Android Simulator, Desktop browsers`
But when I deploy it on `iPhone` the back buttons stop working. I am adding an attribute `data-rel="back"` in my anchor tags, to go back. (As mentioned in the jQM docs)

From my `index.html` I call, `menu.html`. When I click `back` button (not browser back button) on the `menu.html` app doesn't come back on `index.html`

This problem is there only for `iPhone`.

This is how my `index.html` looks like

```
        <div id="content_home" class="mainColumn" data-role="page">
            <div class="header">
                <a href="Menu.html"  id="home_nav_btn" class="headerButton nav fr" style=""><span></span></a>
                <a id="bg" class="headerButton home fl" style=""><span></span></a>
                <h1><img src="images/bank_trust.png" alt=""></h1>
            </div>
            <!-- Remaining HTML Code -->
        </div>
```

And my Menu.html looks like this,

```
<div id="content_nav" class="mainColumn" data-role="page">
    <div class="header">
        <a id="btn_signout" class="headerButton fr" style=""><span>Signout</span></a>
        <a data-rel="back" class="headerButton home fl" ><span></span></a>
        <h1><img src="images/bank_trust.png" alt=""></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this myself...

jQM docs say that you must have `href` attribute which gives a semantic meaning to your anchor. I added `href` attribute and its all working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [history.back](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.navigation.js), i hope this help.

Comment: Hi. thanks for responding. Ofcourse I can use `history.back`. I just wanted to avoid doing it from `javascript`